# click binding for checkbox not working properly in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox and textbox. I want textbox to be empty and not editable whenever checkbox is not selected.

Part where I have to disable the textbox when textbox is un-selected works fine but emptying part does not work fine because I have to use checkbox's click binding for it and as soon as I use click binding, it breaks the checkbox behavior and it becomes unclickable. I have a jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/qK5Y3/16/

and a code sample below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="emailTemplateSendAtTime" name="emailTemplateSendAtTime" data-bind="checked:SendAtTime, click:ClickSendAtTime"/>
<input type="text" style="width: 250px" id="emailTemplateSendAtTimeProperty" data-bind="value: SendAtTimeProperty, enable:SendAtTime"/>
```

This is my js:

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    this.SendAtTimeProperty = ko.observable("Something");
    this.SendAtTime = ko.observable();



    this.ClickSendAtTime = function () {
                if (model.SendAtTime() == false) {
                    model.SendAtTimeProperty("");
                }
            };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things:

- add `model` as parameter for `ClickSendAtTime`
- return true on `ClickSendAtTime` to avoid cancelling the event

  ```
  var ViewModel = function () {

      this.SendAtTimeProperty = ko.observable("Something");
      this.SendAtTime = ko.observable();

      this.ClickSendAtTime = function (model) {
              if (model.SendAtTime() == false) {
                  model.SendAtTimeProperty("");
              }
              return true;
          };
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
  ```

Another way to define `ClickSendAtTime`

```
this.ClickSendAtTime = function () {
      if (this.SendAtTime() == false) {
          this.SendAtTimeProperty("");
      }
      return true;
};
```

Some information about why you need to return true

> **Allowing the default action**
>
> By default, Knockout will prevent the event from taking any default action. For example if you use the event binding to capture the keypress event of an input tag, the browser will only call your handler function and will not add the value of the key to the input element’s value. A more common example is using the click binding, which internally uses this binding, where your handler function will be called, but the browser will not navigate to the link’s href. This is a useful default because when you use the click binding, it’s normally because you’re using the link as part of a UI that manipulates your view model, not as a regular hyperlink to another web page.
>
> However, if you do want to let the default action proceed, just return true from your event handler function.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That worked. Although I am not clear about why should I return true to avoid canceling the event? Can you explain me in little more details? or direct me to an article which discusses this in more details?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `ViewModel` the variable `model` is not defined so you should remove it and instead use `this` and inside the checkbox click `event` return true so that the event work as normal (if you didn't return anything or false the event 'll be as if it has been cancelled)

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    self = this;
    self.SendAtTimeProperty = ko.observable("Something");
    self.SendAtTime = ko.observable();
    this.ClickSendAtTime = function () {
        if (self.SendAtTime() == false) {
            self.SendAtTimeProperty("");
        }
        return true;
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: You are correct. But I do not remember returning true on any of the event bindings while using knock out. What is so special about this one?

Comment: here you are using the click event..for example if you want to stop that event you simply **return false;** , try to use check event and you 'll see that you don't need to return anything

Comment: for example, the same viewmodel has add function which is bound to the Add button with click binding and  following code works fine: model.Add = function () {
                var data = {
                    ID: "",
                    Name: "",
                    FromAddress: "",
                    Subject: "",
                    Body: "",
                    CampaignId: model.CampaignId(),
                    DefaultToAddress: "",
                    SendAtTimeProperty: "",
                    SendAtTime: false
                };

                model.LoadEditBox(data);
            };.